# Gtk3 and Python - Searchbar doesn't fill window

Tags: python, gtk3, searchbar

I'm writing a sort of searchbar using Gtk3 and Python. I have a window with a searchbar and a searchentry to type text and to search stuff.The searchbar is in a grid.
The only problem I got is that this searchbar doesn't fill the window but remains at the center of it. 
Is there any way to do this?
Here's my code.Thanks.

```
    window = Gtk.Window()
    window.set_default_size(500, -1)
    window.connect("destroy", lambda q: Gtk.main_quit())

    grid = Gtk.Grid()
    window.add(grid)

    searchbar = Gtk.SearchBar()
    searchbar.set_search_mode(True)
    grid.attach(searchbar, 0, 1, 1, 1)

    searchentry = Gtk.SearchEntry()
    searchentry.connect("activate",on_clicked)

    searchbar.connect_entry(searchentry)
    searchbar.add(searchentry)
```